# The voice he "made/took/sounded/spoke" on the phone call was not very sweet

Tags: verbs

Is "**voice**" on the phone call what we **make** or **take** or **sound** or **speak**?

> E.g, *The **voice** he **made/took/sounded/spoke** on the phone call was not very sweet.*

1. My guess is "**make**" is the most general verb that can take **voice** as an object. I guess this focuses on his action itself in the sentence.
2. For "**take**", it seems to focus on his deliberate choice of expressing an intention through the tone of the **voice**.
3. The verb "**sound**" seems to focus on the **voice** itself as a sound but I am not sure this is grammatical.
4. For "**speak**", it seems to focus on the content of what is described through the **voice**.

Even if this question might feel silly and absurd, I would be very grateful if this is genuinely regarded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiomatic expression is to **take a tone** or to *use* a **tone of voice**.

> Don't take that tone with me!
>
> Don't use that tone with me!
>
> Don't use that tone of voice with me!

These are reprimands, often of a teenage child by their parent.

But you can also say

> His voice was not very friendly when we spoke.
>
> He did not sound very happy when we spoke.
>
> His tone of voice was hostile when we spoke.
>
> When training a dog, a harsh tone of voice is used for punishment and a sweet one for reward.

P.S. To respond to your comment to Vero's answer, about the sound of a person's voice when the phone wakes them up, you are correct that the verbs **use** or **take** would be inappropriate if the speaker was truly groggy, but these verbs could be appropriate if the speaker was deliberately intending to express either displeasure at having been awakened or a lack of desire to do anything but go back to sleep.

> He sounded sleepy on the phone.
>
> He used an exaggerated tone of exhaustion when I phoned him at 4AM  and asked him to come into the office several hours early today.

Comment: Thank you for answering and all those example sentences that are a great help. But, I think, here, **take** or **use** seem to show deliberate behavior of it. Is there a verb of a neutral meaning? How about **make**? And are all the articles from 1 to 4 in the question incorrect grammatically and never used?

Comment: We can take a tone, adopt a tone, use a tone, but we do not **make a voice** or **make a tone**.  If you want to suggest that the tone is not being deliberately taken, you can make **tone** the subject of the sentence: **His tone was...**

Comment: Yes, that's right. If it's not deliberate the sentence has to be changed somewhat. Perhaps 'sound' is the word you're looking for. 'His voice sounded indifferent.', for example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer which sorts out everything, Tᴚoɯɐuo. This answer helps me a lot and would also help many others.

Answer (score 7):

For your sentence most native English speakers would say 'used'. 
"The voice he used was...."
If you don't like the 'sound' of someone's voice, because it seems superior or arrogant, you can say, "Don't use that tone of voice with me."

Comment: Thank you for answering. :) But, isn't **use** only used in a case the speaker deliberately speaks in such a tone of voice? E.g, when somebody woke up in the early morning and answered a call, that person's voice would sound a little tired or lacking energy. Also for this situation, can we say ***He used a tired tone of voice.***?